# Changing excel cell data with user input? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I got an excel sorta view working on swiftUI. But I'm having trouble finding a way to be able to change the value of single cell in the excel view. Currently, each cell shows the current (row, col) that it belongs to, but I want to be able for the user to be able to click on any cell and be able to change the value.

I tried using a textField but I'm confused how in any way it will interact with a single cell in the whole excel sorta view. Thanks for the help.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let columns = 20
    let rows = 30
    
    @State private var offset = CGPoint.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                // empty corner
                Color.clear.frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                ScrollView([.vertical]) {
                    rowsHeader
                        .offset(y: offset.y)
                }
                .disabled(true)
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ScrollView([.horizontal]) {
                    colsHeader
                        .offset(x: offset.x)
                }
                .disabled(true)

                table
                    .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    var colsHeader: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<columns) { col in
                Text("COL \(col)")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                    .border(Color.blue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var rowsHeader: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<rows) { row in
                Text("ROW \(row)")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                    .border(Color.blue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var table: some View {
        ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal]) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<rows) { row in
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(0..<columns) { col in
                            // Cell
                            Text("(\(row), \(col))")
                                .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                                .border(Color.blue)
                                .id("\(row)_\(col)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .background( GeometryReader { geo in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self, value: geo.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin)
            })
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { value in
                print("offset >> \(value)")
                offset = value
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGPoint
    static var defaultValue = CGPoint.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value.x += nextValue().x
        value.y += nextValue().y
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach, using a `ExelModel` data model for the cells with a 2D array of Strings, to allow editing of your cells.

However, in my tests, the UI response was not good at all.

But you may be able to recycle the code to make a more responsive UI.

```
class ExelModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tableData: [[String]] = []
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let columns = 10
    let rows = 10

    @StateObject var model = ExelModel()  // <-- here
    @State var selected = "" // <-- here
    
    @State private var offset = CGPoint.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                // empty corner
                Color.clear.frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                ScrollView([.vertical]) {
                    rowsHeader
                        .offset(y: offset.y)
                }
                .disabled(true)
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ScrollView([.horizontal]) {
                    colsHeader
                        .offset(x: offset.x)
                }
                .disabled(true)
                if !model.tableData.isEmpty {  // <-- here
                    table.coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {  // <-- here
            model.tableData = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: "", count: columns), count: rows)
        }
    }
    
    var colsHeader: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<columns) { col in
                Text("COL \(col)")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                    .border(Color.blue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var rowsHeader: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<rows) { row in
                Text("ROW \(row)")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                    .border(Color.blue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var table: some View {
            ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal]) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<rows) { row in
                        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(0..<columns) { col in
                                // Cell
                                TextField("", text: $model.tableData[row][col])
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                                    .border(Color.blue)
                                    .id("\(row)_\(col)")
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        selected = "\(row)_\(col)"  // <-- here
                                    }
                                    .background(selected == "\(row)_\(col)" ? Color.green : Color.white) // <-- here
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background( GeometryReader { geo in
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self, value: geo.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin)
                })
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { value in
                //    print("offset >> \(value)")
                    offset = value
                }
            }
    }
    
}
```

EDIT-1:

to make the UI more responsive,
use the following code with `@FocusState` and both a `TextField` and a `Text`.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let columns = 20
    let rows = 30

    @StateObject var model = ExelModel()  // <-- here
    @State var selected = "" // <-- here
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool  // <-- here
    
    @State private var offset = CGPoint.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                // empty corner
                Color.clear.frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                ScrollView([.vertical]) {
                    rowsHeader
                        .offset(y: offset.y)
                }
                .disabled(true)
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ScrollView([.horizontal]) {
                    colsHeader
                        .offset(x: offset.x)
                }
                .disabled(true)
                if !model.tableData.isEmpty {  // <-- here
                    table.coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {  // <-- here
            model.tableData = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: "", count: columns), count: rows)
        }
    }
    
    var colsHeader: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<columns) { col in
                Text("COL \(col)")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                    .border(Color.blue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var rowsHeader: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<rows) { row in
                Text("ROW \(row)")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                    .border(Color.blue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var table: some View {
            ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal]) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<rows) { row in
                        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(0..<columns) { col in
                                
                                // --- here
                                if selected == "\(row)_\(col)" {
                                    TextField("", text: $model.tableData[row][col])
                                        .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                                        .border(Color.blue)
                                        .id("\(row)_\(col)")
                                        .background(Color.green)
                                        .focused($isFocused)
                                        .task {
                                            self.isFocused = true
                                        }
                                } else {
                                    Text(model.tableData[row][col])
                                        .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                                        .border(Color.blue)
                                        .id("\(row)_\(col)")
                                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            selected = "\(row)_\(col)"
                                            isFocused = true
                                        }
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background( GeometryReader { geo in
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self, value: geo.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin)
                })
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { value in
                    offset = value
                }
            }
    }
    
}
```